# it is possible to create a web server on the fly with PHP for a particular test in a unit test? (PHPUnit)

Tags: php, unit-testing, curl

I need to test different behaviors of my lib depending on the response of a curl request.

The lib change the curl options depending on the function arguments, so I need to test that the request is made in the right way, and also that the response is formatted as wanted

My idea for the tests is to:

// create webserver  (maybe using php -S)

// make the curl request to a test file (localhost:8000/test.php)

// assert that the response has what I looking for

By now  I was unable to create the web server.  I'am using this to create a background process for the webserver

```
exec('php -S localhost:8000 > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!');
```

Maybe there is a different approach for what I'm doing

Answer (score 1):

I google it better,

The answer is to create the server on the bootstrap file

```
<?php

// Command that starts the built-in web server
$command = sprintf(
    'php -S %s:%d -t %s >/dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!',
    WEB_SERVER_HOST,
    WEB_SERVER_PORT,
    WEB_SERVER_DOCROOT
);

// Execute the command and store the process ID
$output = array(); 
exec($command, $output);
$pid = (int) $output[0];

echo sprintf(
    '%s - Web server started on %s:%d with PID %d', 
    date('r'),
    WEB_SERVER_HOST, 
    WEB_SERVER_PORT, 
    $pid
) . PHP_EOL;

// Kill the web server when the process ends
register_shutdown_function(function() use ($pid) {
    echo sprintf('%s - Killing process with ID %d', date('r'), $pid) . PHP_EOL;
    exec('kill ' . $pid);
});

// More bootstrap code
```

Here is the full article were I found the answer

http://tech.vg.no/2013/07/19/using-phps-built-in-web-server-in-your-test-suites/